# Function and LINQ query not working as needed

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, listbox

```
Public Class Records
    Dim Items() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Inventory.txt")
    Dim Parts(7) As String

    Private Sub Records_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lstOuput.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFullList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFullList.Click
        Dim x As String = ""
        Dim TheFullList = From Thing In Items
                          Let Parts = Thing.Split(" "c)
                          Let TheRoom = RoomName(x)
                          Let ItemNumber = Parts(0)
                          Let ItemName = Parts(1)
                          Let PurchaseDate = Parts(3)
                          Let PurchasePrice = Parts(4)
                          Let Result = ItemNumber & " " & ItemName & " " & " " & PurchaseDate & " " & PurchasePrice
                          Order By ItemNumber
                          Select Result

        For Each Thing In TheFullList
            lstOuput.Items.Add(Thing)
            lstOuput.Items.Add(" ")
            lstOuput.Items.Add(RoomName(x))
        Next
    End Sub
    Function RoomName(x As String) As String
        Dim TheOutput As String = ""
        Dim GetRoomQuery = From TheRoom In Items
                           Let Parts = TheRoom.Split(" "c)
                           Let ActualName = Parts(0)
                           Let TrimmedName = Parts(0).Substring(0, 2)
                           Select TrimmedName
        If GetRoomQuery(0) = "LVR" Then
            TheOutput = "Living Room"
        End If
        Return TheOutput
    End Function

    Private Sub btnFindItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnID_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnID.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDepreciation_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDepreciation.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFindYear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindYear.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

The array Items() is formed from reading a textfile name "Inventory.txt".
What I want to do is get the "Item Number" part of the LINQ query from the btnFullList event procedure. I then want to take that information and put in into a function that will look at the first three characters and use an IF block to determine the correct output.

The problem right now is that nothing is returned and I get a NullException error upon clicking the button.

Also, in the btnFullList procedure LINQ query there was once much more parts to the result, however I deleted them. Upon clicking the button the results I deleted are still being shown, even after editing the text file the array read from.

Comment: `Items` is declared in the loop, do you know it has been initialized? Debug and check all objects.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that Items is initialized at the class level.

Comment: Which line throws the NRE

Comment: In the For Each Loop, the last listbox output. (lstouput.items.add(RoomName(x))

Comment: try this for you split `TheRoom.Split(New Char() {" "c})`

Comment: You're not handling when Parts(0) is less than 2. `Let TrimmedName = Parts(0).Substring(0, 2)` throws an error when you try to do this to one character.

Comment: In this part...`lstOuput.Items.Add(RoomName(x))`    where does x get its value?

Comment: Parts(0) will always be 3 characters, there is no possibility of it being any less or any more.

Comment: x gets (or is supposed to get) its value from a function call statement.

Comment: Well it does not appear to have a value here and from what I can tell, RoomName won't like that.

Comment: So RoomName is not using x so it won't complain. Maybe try actually setting a default value for your x and y. Like empty string for instance. Why is RoomName taking x and not doing anything with it?

Comment: Since Strings are reference types you could set x in the function using `x = TheOutput`   that should work, but you may need to add `ByRef` to the parameter declaration.

Comment: I've declared x as an empty string and did what you suggested but the function is still not returning anything.

Comment: Can you explain your purpose for passing x into RoomName?

Comment: With x and y being empty the whole time is giving you the empty results. Setting x and y to empty string should have prevented a null argument exception.

Comment: I guess I intended to use it but never did.

Comment: Show the code that sets `Items`

Comment: Public Class Records
    Dim Items() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Inventory.txt")

Comment: ok so it looks like you are not using the output of the LINQ. You should be using the variable `TheFullList` some where in there, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the loop that you really want. Your LINQ output should be the loop's collection.

```
For Each Thing In TheFullList

            lstOuput.Items.Add(Thing)
            lstOuput.Items.Add(" ")
            lstOuput.Items.Add(RoomName(x))


        Next
```

The other thing you should note is that you can simplify your LINQ output to be a list like this.

```
Dim lstOutput As List(Of Object) = TheFullList.ToList()
```

There is also a few errors in you RoomName Function. See my comments below.

```
Function RoomName(x As String) As String
        Dim TheOutput As String
        Dim GetRoomQuery = From TheRoom In Items
                           Let Parts = TheRoom.Split(" "c)
                           Let ActualName = Parts(0)
                           'I changed this to be length of 3 to match what you are doing in the IF
                           Let TrimmedName = Parts(0).Substring(0, 3)
                           Select TrimmedName

        'Here i am using the output of the LINQ
        If GetRoomQuery  = "LVR" Then
            TheOutput = "Living Room"
        End If
        Return TheOutput
    End Function
```

Comment: Yes, that is the loop I want, but I still am not getting what I need from the function. I set TheOutput to a string literal and I can get that to display but it seems that the function is not scanning Parts(0) for the desired substring.

Comment: In the RoomName function, I don't believe you can reference Parts(0) in the IF statement.  I'm updating my answer with that code.

Comment: The IF statement should reference the LINQ output like I have. You really should declare you LINQ output so that it's clear what it is returning. I had to think for a minute to see it was simply a string.

Comment: Also it looks like you should use `.Substring(0, 3)` because you need a length of three.

Comment: Well, it looks like the problem has been found. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.